# can not fullscreen display with OpenGL ES2 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am trying to play H.264 videos with OpenGL ES2 on my iPhone 5s, and i have pictures on screen already.However,the picture won't fill the entire screen althouth i tried to use different vertex position and texCoord. I also checked the glViewport is (0, 0, 640, 1136) on my 5s.

This is the
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVvL0.png).

And my settings:

```
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f
}; 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);

GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXCOORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, texCoords);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Does anyone have ideas about this problem.Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit**

This is my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
uniform float preferredRotation;

varying vec2 texCoordVarying;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = position;
    texCoordVarying = texCoord;
}
```

and my fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 texCoordVarying;
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D SamplerY;
uniform sampler2D SamplerUV;
uniform mat3 colorConversionMatrix;

void main(void) {
    mediump vec3 yuv;
    lowp vec3 rgb;
    yuv.x = texture2D(SamplerY, texCoordVarying).r - (16.0/255.0);
    yuv.yz = texture2D(SamplerUV, texCoordVarying).rg - vec2(0.5, 0.5);

    rgb = colorConversionMatrix * yuv;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1);

 //   gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

**SOLVED**

Sorry for my mistake that i tried to use 'glBindAttribLocation' before 'glLinkProgram'.Things appear OK now after i change their position.

Comment: What's your vertex shader?

Comment: ... and does stuff move around at all when you use different vertex coordinates? I'd recommend disabling the video for now, and just use a constant color fragment shader so you can see what is ending up where on screen.

Comment: @Isogen74 I paste my vertex shader above.Yes, the picture move around when i use different vertex coordinates, and when i just use gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1) in my fragment shader, there is also only a red rectangle in the upper right corner of the screen.

Comment: @Isogen74 I think i find the problem, it's the texCoordVarying.After i remove the line: "texCoordVarying = texCoord" and just use gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1) in my fragment shader, the screen is full of red color. But i still don't understand why.

Comment: Does the video actually fill the entire surface of the texture memory? You might just be getting a black region of the texture being loaded.

Comment: @Isogen74 Sorry for my mistake that i tried to use 'glBindAttribLocation' before 'glLinkProgram'.Things appear OK now after i change their position.Anyway,thanks for sharing.